# Where does magento save UI Grid filter data?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, filter, data

Where does magento save UI component Grid applied filter data?

Deleted session table but applied filter data does not save there

Answer (score 5):

Magento 2 saves admin user UI preferences in the database in `ui_bookmark` table.